# Зарезервированное i равное undefined

Tags: javascript

Отладчик пишет, что i,j,m в цикле for равно undefined, но при этом я i зарезервировал.
Сам код:

```
var wordNumber = 0;
    function createNumberAndDoArr() {
        while (wordNumber < 100)
            wordNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

        word = wordNumber + "";
        var arrWord = word.split("");
        return arrWord;
    };

    function compare() {
        var arrWord = createNumberAndDoArr()
        var k = 0;

        result = (document.forms["form"].elements["numbers"].value + "").split("");

        while (k !== 0) {
            for (var i = 0, j = 0, m = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                if ((arrWord[i] == result[k]) && (i == k)) {
                    j++;
                }   else if ((arrWord[i] == result[k]) && !(i == k)) {
                    m++;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }
        return[j, m];
    }
```

Comment: `var k = 0; ... while (k !== 0) {` - код в `while` не зайдет. "я i зарезервировал" - это что значит?

Comment: Да, глупая ошибка. Но спасибо, я теперь понял)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код эквивалентен:

```
function compare() {
    var arrWord = createNumberAndDoArr()
    var k = 0;
    var i, j, m; // здесь они undefined

    result = (document.forms["form"].elements["numbers"].value + "").split("");

    while (k !== 0) {
        // сюда мы не попадаем, так как k - ноль
        for (i = 0, j = 0, m = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            if ((arrWord[i] == result[k]) && (i == k)) {
                j++;
            }   else if ((arrWord[i] == result[k]) && !(i == k)) {
                m++;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    return[j, m]; // вернет [undefined, undefined]
}
```

Comment: Да, глупая ошибка)) Но все равно спасибо, я понял.